# Steps to find the canonical form of conic section

Tags: matrices, conic-sections, matrix-equations

I have to find the canonical form of the conic:

$x^2+4xy+3y^2-2x+1=0$

I'm not sure if all these steps are correct, I would appreciate if you could check.

First of all I can say that this is an hyperbola since $\begin{vmatrix}A\end{vmatrix} \ne 0 $ and $\begin{vmatrix}Q\end{vmatrix} < 0$

\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix}
A
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix} 
1 & 2 & -1 \\
2 & 3 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 
\end{vmatrix} = -4
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix}
Q
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix} 
1 & 2 \\
2 & 3  
\end{vmatrix} = -1
\end{align}

$Q$ being the matrix of the quadratic form and $A$ the matrix of the quadratic equation.

Now I know that the canonical form is like

$\lambda X^2 + \mu Y^2 + p = 0$

Eigenvalues of $Q$ are

\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix} 
1-\lambda & 2 \\
2 & 3-\lambda  
\end{vmatrix} = (1-\lambda)(3-\lambda)-4 = \lambda^2-4\lambda-1 = 0
\end{align}

We find that the solution to this equation is $\lambda = 2 - \sqrt5$, $\mu = 2 + \sqrt5$

Now I put the found solutions in the canonical form we had before, so now it becomes

$(2-\sqrt5)X^2+(2+\sqrt5)Y^2+p=0$

We need to find $p$ now.
We know that the canonical form and the non-canonical form of the conic have the same matrix determinant, so

\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix}
A'
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
(2-\sqrt5) & 0 & 0 \\
0 & (2+\sqrt5) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & p
\end{vmatrix} = -p = -4
\end{align}

Let's put $p$ in the quation and we get:

$(2-\sqrt5)X^2+(2+\sqrt5)Y^2+4=0$

We've now found the canonical form of the conic, we need one last step.

We divide by $p$ in this case so that the equation can result clearer to interpret.

$(2-\sqrt5)X^2+(2+\sqrt5)Y^2=-4$

$-\frac{2-\sqrt5}{4}X^2-\frac{2+\sqrt5}{4}Y^2=1$

Comment: Seem OK. Not checked the actual calculation

Comment: The mathematical part is ok, I double checked.

Comment: I would ask you a question. When I chose $\lambda$ and $\mu$ I gave them randomly one of the Eigenvalues. Is it ok to do that or there's a specific Eigenvalue that must be assigned either to $\lambda$ or $\mu$ ?

Comment: @matt95 Not really. Swapping them amounts to swapping the $X$ and $Y$ axes. For a hyperbola, this means that you might end up with $Y^2/b^2-X^2/a^2+p=0$, which is still correct, but unconventional.

Comment: So which Eigenvalue goes to $\lambda$ and which to $\mu$? Is there a general rule? Maybe $a<b$?

Comment: @matt95 If you’ve got a hyperbola, one eigenvalue is positive and the other negative. Since convention puts the minus sign on the $Y^2$ term, assign the negative eigenvalue to $\mu$. For an ellipse in standard position, the major axis conventionally coincides with the $X$-axis. The eigenvalues will have the same sign in that case, so you want the one with the *smaller* absolute value to go with $X^2$.

Comment: BTW, since the canonical-form matrix is diagonal, its determinant is the product of its diagonal elements, so $p=|A|/\lambda\mu$.

Comment: By “not really” in my comment above, I meant that it doesn’t really matter.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation!